# facebook graph api {app-id|app-secret} call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm doing some tests with the facebook graph api and i cannot get all the pages from a response pagination when i use the {app-id|app-secret} in the url as an access token. However, it works when i use the access token generated via graph explorer.

What can i do to get all pages using the {app-id|app-secret} method?

Thast's my graph api call:

https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/{user-id}/feed?limit=100&access_token={app-id}|{app-secret}&until=1409652886

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of App-ID and App-Secret is called "App Access Token", and since there is no relation to any User, you cannot get the User feed with it. The App Access Token is only there for public stuff from Facebook Pages and certain other things like changing App Settings or sending App Notifications. See the following links for detailed information about the different Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

To read the user feed (including pagination), you can only use a User Access Token with the `read_stream` permission.

Comment: How about having a long-lived token for this matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403454/generate-long-lived-access-token-for-facebook-graph-api

Comment: long-lived tokens are explained very well in the 2 links i posted